# JUnitCore: the best way to test java files or are there better ways?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I am currently creating my own custom application for myself to compile Java files. I have the application compiling Java files perfectly but now I want to start adding some type of testing for the Java files (e.g. I pass in some variables to a number of different files - all doing the same thing - being tested and compare the results to what I expect them to be)... kinda like how JUnit works

I have been looking at JUnitCore to add onto my application to do this but I'm still unsure on how it works. Are there any good tutorials that explain JUnitCore or are there any better ways to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1):

JUnit should be the way to go... as it is simple and you can be up and running in pretty short time.

Here are a couple of links...

1. [Junit 4](http://www.mkyong.com/unittest/junit-4-tutorial-1-basic-usage/)
2. [Junit.org](http://www.junit.org/)
3. [Software Testing via Junit](http://www.softwaretestingtutorials.com/junit-tutorial-for-beginners/)

EDIT: As per the comment :
Here is an example:
Class `WayA` to compute sum

```
class WayA {
    public int sum(int a, int b){
         return a+b;
    }   
}
```

Another Class `WayB` to do the same

```
class WayB {
    public int sum(int a, int b){
        int sum = a;
        for(int i=1;i<=b;i++)
            sum++;
        return sum;
    }   
}
```

And here you go with the test case:

```
class WayTest extends TestCase {
    WayA wayA;
    WayB wayB;

    public void setUp() {
        wayA = new WayA();
        wayB = new WayB();
    }

    public void testAdd() {
        int a = 9, b = 3;
        assertEquals(wayA.sum(a, b), wayB.sum(a, b));
    }

    public void tearDown() {
        wayA = null;
        wayB = null;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: does JUnit allow you to run the same test on a number of different java files without changing any code? By changing any code I mean without having to call the class you are testing, can a test be set up to run for multiple files?

Comment: I just made an edit as per my understanding of your statement. Two classes doing almost same type of work and can be tested via one `TestCase`.